# Best way to implement public blockchain for IoT?

Tags: networking, wireless, mesh-networks

I'm attempting to build a blockchain network of IoT devices that would allow public access such that any person around the world could push data to it and there would be an immutable record of all data pledged to the network.  The validity of the data or the trust of the client isn't important, but keeping a permanent ledger of all activity is.  Reducing centralization is also important for this particular application, hence the need for blockchain. What is the best way to go about creating such a system?  What consensus algorithm is best for this application?  Proof of work seems like overkill.  Proof of stake?  Would proof of authority be best?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is the right place to ask. Unless you're trying to figure out how to implement the code on the very low power CPUs that are generally used in IoT devices, and even then, this probably isn't the right place to ask.

Comment: Why the need for IoT ? It appears that you are building some sort of p-p file sharing network, with some additional authentication, etc features, built on top of a block chain.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited for https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Samuel, please let us know if you have any thoughts. If no response soon, this topic may be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i'll put it on crypto instead.